# How to make fade image slider when hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make an fade image slider. in Netflix when i hover on movies i can see screenshots from movie with fade image slider in background.
in html i have this:

```
<div class="top-moviez-post-images">
                <img class="slide-01" src="images/outlander-top-moviez-01.jpg" alt="outlaner">
                <img class="slide-02" src="images/outlander-top-moviez-02.jpg" alt="outlaner">
            </div>
```

please help me do that...

and I'm not well in english :(

Thank you

Comment: I recommend to use one that's already made, if not this one: http://www.cincopa.com/media-platform/services/create-slideshow

Comment: Your question is too broad, I agree with @TomBurris above, use a pre-built library.

Comment: actually, I searched but i could't find any slider like netflixs. but if you guys know how to make some thing like that please help me.